# Android: Navigation Drawer SubMenu: How to Collapsible navigation items

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer with 10 options
Option #5 shoudl have another 7 options (like a sub menu) of some sort that is expandable/collapsible

How do I create a "Collapsible navigation items" like it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Content)?

Comment: It's an ExpandableListView, you can add child only to parent 5.

Comment: @Milanix Actually I need to add children to Parent 5 & Parent 7, is that not possible?

Comment: So what's the problem? Use ExplandableListView as said earlier.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a sample application which makes it:

> <strike>[*PrashamTrivedi / DrawerLayoutTest*](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest)</strike>: Link is dead
>
> **EDIT: [Simple Navigational Drawer Layout in Android](http://dharmangsoni.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/simple-navigational-drawer-layout-in.html)**

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_group_item,parent,false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
        convertView.setTag(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }
```

---

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) children.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_submenu_item,parent,false);
        }

        text = (TextView) convertView;
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setTag(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        return convertView;
}
```

And you have to create the new xml files in the layout folder (*hint*: create two, one for the group view and other for the submenu)

After all your side navigation must look like as below:

[image]

Comment: But after I've imported your project solution into my workspace, I wasn't able to select the item under Item 4. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, as I remember, the sample project wasn't completely backward-compatible meaning that it has min-sdk version 11. If you used the app in older devices which have before Honeycomb API, it might be the cause. If not, please consider the advice I've told: "_you have to create the new xml files in the layout folder (hint: create two, one for the group view and other for the submenu)_".

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: Yeah the link is broken, does anyone know where this project is now? According to the screenshot it allows the use of both ListView and ExpandableListView which is something I need help with myself.

Comment: dead link ... sorry