# How to create drawer navigation like this?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer, drawerlayout

[image: I want to create the drawer exactly look like this]

Hi guys, I wanna create the drawer navigation. I have read some docs, but it didnt work, so I will show u the picture that I want my drawer layout to look like this. Hope you can spend some to help me :)

Comment: the code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149776/android-navigation-drawer-submenu-how-to-collapsible-navigation-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make an ExpandableListView in your NavigationDrawer

ExpandableListView : [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

NavigationDrawer : [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Example :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Menu right -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/menu_droite"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <!-- Liste du menu droite -->
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="480dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:listSelector="#037DA6"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawer docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
You should create your own layout for it and place there an ExpandableListView.
List item should also have custom layout for these blue counters

P.S. Icon at the top right corner is for opening menu, not for navigation drawer. To open drawer you should touch app icon. See guidelines.